CosmosDB for MongoDB updateOne upsert race condition
I'm working on a Nodejs App which stores data in the Azure "CosmosDB for MongoDB API".
Szenario: The app send 2 updateOne at the same time to the DB (simplified):
db.collection("messages").updateOne({uuid: "1234"}, {$set: {foo: {}}}, {upsert: true});
db.collection("messages").updateOne({uuid: "1234"}, {$set: {bar: {}}}, {upsert: true});

The expected result is one document with foo and bar:
{ _id: ..., uuid: "1234", foo: {}, bar: {}}

But sometimes 2 documents are created:
{ _id: ..., uuid: "1234", foo: {}}
{ _id: ..., uuid: "1234", bar: {}}

If an unique index for 'uuid' exists, than an exception (duplicate key) is raised instead of the creation of the second document.
Is there a way to solve the issue on database level? Or is it up to the application to synchronize the database requests?

It would be more preferable to group the 2 operations together as one, but that depends on your actual use case. On the other hand, you might find a transaction useful.

The two updateOne statements are not consecutive in the actual code but are in different sections. Therefore, the statement cannot be combined in the code.

Also, you may want to await the updateOne to be finished like this MongoDB official example
